# struts 2 token Interceptor

Tags: struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I am getting like "WARNING: Could not find token name in params."

In Struts.xml

```
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="entityInterceptor" class="entity.jpa.EntityInterceptor"/>
<interceptor name="sessionInterceptor" class="env.actionitems.struts.SessionInterceptor"/>

<interceptor-stack name="entityStack">
<interceptor-ref name="entityInterceptor"/>
<interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor"/>
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">   
</interceptor-ref>

</interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="entityStack"></default-interceptor-ref>

<action name="*acegitran*jsp*pkg*create*dcode*" method="{1}" class="env.transactions.{3}.{4}">
<interceptor-ref name="token"/> 
<interceptor-ref name="entityStack"/>
<result name="invalid.token">Transaction.{2}iport{5}create</result>
<result name="success" type="tiles">Transaction.{2}iport{5}create</result>
<result name="error" type="tiles">Transaction.{2}iport{5}create</result>
<result name="input" type="tiles">Transaction.{2}iport{5}create</result>
</action>
```

In JSP

```
<s:token name="clientToken"/>
```

Any other parameters should be passed in struts.xml to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You might want to try changing "`invalid.token`" to "`invalid.clientToken`" in the `Struts.xml` file
eg

```
result name="invalid.clientToken"
```

Please remember that the `Struts.xml` file will only take effect after the server is restarted!

Hope that helps